# C programming - Incorrect output of matches

Tags: c

The task is to enter the dimension and data into a two dimensional array and determine the number of non repeating numbers. I tried many things so i asked you to give me your instructions or hints(wanna instructions) how to correct my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int protect(int max_size_1 ,int max_size_2 , int current_1,int current_2,const int arr[max_size_1][max_size_2])
{
    for(int f1=0;f1<max_size_1;f1++)
    {
        for(int f2=0;f2<max_size_2;f2++)
        {
            printf("%d---%d\n",arr[current_1][current_2],arr[f1][f2]);
            if((f1!=current_1 && f2!=current_2) && arr[current_1][current_2]==arr[f1][f2])
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, f1, f2, count=1;
        printf("[i][j] = ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    int arr[i][i];

    for (f1 = 0; f1<i; f1++) 
    {
        for (f2 = 0; f2<i; f2++) 
        {
        printf("a[%d][%d] = ", f1, f2);
        scanf("%d", &arr[f1][f2]);
        }
    }
    for (f1 = 0; f1<i; f1++)  
    {
        for (f2 = 0; f2<i; f2++) 
        {
        if (protect(i,j,f1,f2,arr)==1){
            count++;}
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n%d", count/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't apologize just ask the question.

Comment: Re Task 1: how do you want to specify the "certain" digit?  How many numbers do you want to read, or otherwise how does the program know that the sequence is done?

Comment: Re Task 2: please give us example input.  Is it 15 people in each company (total of 30) or 15 between the two companies?  In either case the answer is create an array for each company, sort by salary and compare index 4 of each array to see which one is higher.

Comment: Also, tell us what you tried... so we know you are trying, and just not just asking us to do your home for you.

Comment: Answer for 1 question:With scanf(), i think.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find help here... provided you respect the site rules. As a new user, you really should read [ask] to know how we expect questions to be asked. Specifically, you are supposed to show you current research and a *honest attempt* to solve the problem yourself. Doing that will help you to ask more precise questions which will receive more easily answers.

Comment: `scanf` is probably the way to go to read the number of numbers and the numbers themselves. Give it a try and come back with some code... not that hard and as I have already said, the question will be better and could more easily receive answers.

Comment: Re answer 1:The number of digits that I want to count is not important, it can be 100 or 5. The program knows about stopping by entering 0 from keyboard. 
Re answer 2: yeah you are right
A little bit later, i'll sned my code. But but it is not finished since I am at a dead end. Also my english can be not so good, because it is not my main language.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are trying to store data in a 2 dimensional array.
and in next step for every value in 2 dim array, trying to find whether there is any dup entry present in array. No sure of your requirement to have data stored in 2 dim array, also there are other optimized way of removing duplicates from user inputs.

> we have n user inputs
> want to print the number of entries which do not have a dup in data entered by user.

assume,
if user input is

```
   1, 1
   1, 1
```

answer should be 0.
for input

```
   1, 2
   3, 4
```

answer should be 4.

could see three issues in the code

1. you have two variables "i" and "j", only one of this var is getting a value assigned , j is always 0. this makes the "protect" function to return a 1 as output for very call.
2. count is started from 1, should be 0
3. result is getting devided by 2, not sure why this is required

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int protect(int max_size_1 ,int max_size_2 , int current_1,int current_2,const int arr[max_size_1][max_size_2])
    {
        for(int f1=0;f1<max_size_1;f1++)
        {
            for(int f2=0;f2<max_size_2;f2++)
            {
                printf("%d---%d\n",arr[current_1][current_2],arr[f1][f2]);
                if((f1!=current_1 && f2!=current_2) && arr[current_1][current_2]==arr[f1][f2])
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int i, j, f1, f2, count=0;
        printf("[i][j] = ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        int arr[i][i];
        j = i;

        for (f1 = 0; f1<i; f1++) 
        {
            for (f2 = 0; f2<i; f2++) 
            {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", f1, f2);
            scanf("%d", &arr[f1][f2]);
            }
        }
        for (f1 = 0; f1<i; f1++)  
        {
            for (f2 = 0; f2<i; f2++) 
            {
                if (protect(i,j,f1,f2,arr)==1){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n%d\n", count);
        return 0;
    }
   ```